# Android: imageSwitcher fit on screen

Tags: android, screen, imageswitcher

I have a problem with imageswitcher to fit on screen. Please check PIC 1. There is still white **free space** on the edge of the screen. I want to achieve the effect in PIC 2. There is no empty space and imageswitcher perfect fit to screen. I can do this efect with imageView using:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

but it looks **centerCrop** doesn't works with imageSwitcher. 
Thanks for any idea how to fix it.

**UPDATE:**

Here is my XML code:
I added there  **android:scaleType="fitXY"** but it didn't help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/imageswitcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/it_intro1" >
    </ImageSwitcher>
```

[image]

**SOLUTION:**
finally it helped add this line of code: **imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);**

```
public View makeView() {

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(Introduction.this);
             imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

            LayoutParams params = new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
            return imageView;

        }
```

Comment: can you post your layout (xml) ? The problem could be with the parent holding the image, also the right scale type for you is FIT_XY

Comment: I tried add there FIT_XY but it didn't help. I updated  my question so now u can see XML layout. Can you please take a look on it? Thanks.

Comment: If you find a solution, you should post here and mark as resolved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** finally it helped add this line of code: imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

```
public View makeView() {

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(Introduction.this);
         imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        LayoutParams params = new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        return imageView;

    }
```

Comment: To keep aspect, you can use imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

Answer (score 0):

In the imageswitcher's xml, set:

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```